# How to draw bounding boxes around classified objects using tensorflow lite?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I would like to know if it is possible to draw bounding boxes using Tensorflow lite. I have been able to draw them using tensorflow-android in version 1.12 but I have no example for drawing bounding boxes in tensorflow lite.

In the code below you can see my way in tensorflow-android 1.12 to get the outputLocations which is working.

```
 inferenceInterface.run(outputNames, logStats);
LOGGER.d("End Section run " + System.currentTimeMillis());
Trace.endSection();

// Copy the output Tensor back into the output array.
Trace.beginSection("fetch");
LOGGER.d("Begin Section fetch " + System.currentTimeMillis());
outputLocations = new float[MAX_RESULTS * 4];
outputScores = new float[MAX_RESULTS];
outputClasses = new float[MAX_RESULTS];
outputNumDetections = new float[1];
inferenceInterface.fetch(outputNames[0], outputLocations);
```

It would be great if you could tell me how to get outputLocations using runInference() from trensorflow-lite instead.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use object detection models such as the following: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync_2018_07_18.tar.gz
The output tensors already have output locations, scores, classes etc. 
You can follow example similar to Android Java sample app:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/demo/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java